# How would I block a specific IP from accessing node.js

Tags: node.js, ejs

I would like to block a specific IP address from accessing my website written in NodeJS, using embedded JS.

[Here is my file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SImo.png) (the important part is chat.ejs and server.js, ignore the other files)

How would I use ejs to block certain IPs from accessing the site? Or even just sending them to another "blocked" page if they visit from a blocked IP, not allowing them to access the main site. It's a small project and only a few people use the site at the moment so I'm not concerned about dynamic IPs or people being blocked with the same IP.

Thanks!

- Colin

Comment: Welcome to SO.   There are plenty of methods of blocking access to your website.  Via firewall,  website configuration, etc.. That said, this isn't actually a programming question but a webserver configuration issue; so probably in Serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned this is more of a 'server' question and can be done many of ways by incorporating an ACL ( access control list )

Depending on where you are hosting (AWS has security groups where you can add CIDR blocks for IP ranges etc) or even on the running web-server (apache, NGINX)

This can also be done in 'code' if you so wish by adding middleware OR conditions in the get request itself. The basic idea is to obtain the client IP via the request object so for example

Lets say you have a 'predefined' array of 'allowed' IP's

```
const ips = ['123.23.232.23','123.23.232.23'] 
let reqIP =  req.connection.remoteAddress //Gets the IP of the requestor
if( reqIP.indexOF(ips) !== -1){
//continue to process the request and return results
 }else{
 //IP not in the list, redirect them to a new page 
 }
```

This is not tested code but the concept should work in allowing you to 'block' specific request by IP however this only works if you know for sure the 'IP' is not dynamic etc

With that said, this is generally better to do on the web-server, otherwise your putting unneeded processes on the node server that could have been blocked at the WS layer OR (in the AWS case) before it even hits the webserver.